# Udp broadcasting in Android And Receving broadcast from the network

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, broadcast

I have to send UDP broadcast in Android.I am always getting **java.io.IOException: Invalid argument** at socket.send(packet).
When creating object of socket I sometimes get **Address already in use** Exception

### My Code Complete code is (Edit 2) :

```
     private void setBroadCastMessage() {
    final int udpPortNumber = 6000;
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (mWifi.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {


            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        try {
                            InetAddress address;
                            address=InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
                            DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(udpPortNumber,address);
                            messageBroadCast(datagramSocket,address);

                        } catch (SocketException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();


        }

    }
}
public void messageBroadCast(DatagramSocket socket, InetAddress address)
{


    String data="This is my discovery request";
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
            address, 6000);
    try {
        socket.send(packet);
        LogUtils.errorLog("Address :"," "+address);
        LogUtils.errorLog("Send String:"," "+data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. Maybe post the stack trace

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: I don't think it is a complete sample as there is no definition for `socket` but assuming that the socket is set up, it definitely compiles.

Comment: @Kuffs It can't 'definitely compile' if there is no definition for `socket`, but in any case there will be an error '`address` may not have been initialized'.

Comment: Right , Its compiling and gives exception at run time.

for reference I writing codes for code also :
DatagramSocket socket = null;
        try {
             socket = new DatagramSocket(6000,address);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: I haven't fixed anything. I just assumed that he had declared his socket in code not shown. I didn't see the need to mention the "address not initialised" error as that is trivial and not really relevant to the problem.

Comment: @KumarRaj You may have subsequently fixed several compilation errors, including the ones already mentioned, but the code posted in this question does not compile. Post the real code.

Comment: @Kuffs So when you said 'your code looks OK' and 'it definitely compiles' you knew it wasn't so?

Comment: @EJP , Thanks for your support. I am posting my complete code.
wait.

Answer (score -1):

Can't really post this as a comment but here is the code I have used which works and is extremely similar to yours.

Try this and add your stack trace to the question if you have further issues.

I use this to successfully broadcast to IP address "255.255.255.255"

```
private void sendToIP(String ip, int port, String message) {

    try {

        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        byte[] sendData = message.getBytes();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
        socket.send(sendPacket);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to broadcast, you may need to call [`DatagramSocket.setBroadcast(true)`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setBroadcast(boolean)). But broadcast of the type you're attempting here has been deprecated for over 20 years.